# Connecting to a Remote SQL Server 2008 PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm facing this error while trying to connect to a remote SQL Server 2008.

```
   SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider:     Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
```

I use the following code to connect to the database.

```
   $dsn = 'sqlsrv:server=SERVER_NAME:1433 ; database=testDB';
   $user = 'user';
   $password = 'password';
   $dbConn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
```

When I try to connect using sqlcmd from a command prompt I'm able to connect to the database. I tried connecting using the command :

```
   SQLCMD -U user -P password -S SERVER_NAME,1433
```

What might be causing this issue? I also do not have SQL Configuration manager installed in the server. How can I fix/debug this issue?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct the connection would fail in the command above. I completely read over that part. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: Try using IP instead of hostname... sounds like DNS issue.